# CUPS send multiple jobs to IPP printer

Tags: linux, printing, cups

Is there a way to let CUPS just queue jobs to an IPP printer while it haven't yet completed the last job?

Background:
We have a XEROX WorkCentre printer which has its own job queue.
Every time someone wants to print they have to spool the job, insert their payment card into the printer and select their job on the printers touchpad.
But when using CUPS on a central server, CUPS only spools the next job when the last one completed, so that only the one who spooled first can see and pay for their job.

We need to use IPP as when using e.g. JetDirect the username isn't transmitted and the users can'T identify their jobs.

Comment: This should probably be moved to ServerFault or Unix Stackexchange

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try using the `waitjob=false` and/or `waitprinter=false` CUPS options:

`ipp://host/queue?waitjob=false&waitprinter=false`

The options are described at 
http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-2.0/network.html#IPP, although I'm not sure what the difference between `waitjob` and `waitprinter` is.

Comment: Thanks! Fot the sake of completeness: I found the difference between `waitjob` and `waitprinter`. `waitjob=false` means that CUPS will remove the job from the queue directly after submitting which causes the next job in the queue to be processed. `waitprinter=false` means that CUPS won't wait for the printer to signal that it's idle before a job is sent. In our case both options were required.